# Ask for permissions with API 22 Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In the project I'm working, we have a set of permissions, and 3 of them, are tagged as `dangerous`. In devices with Android < Android 6.0.0 there are no problems, but with the newest version, the app can't work properly.

So, searching in google about permissions, I arrived to Google Documentation page, where talk about how to request it: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html

They use this code.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { ... }
```

Where `ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(..)` is only in API 23.

But the problem comes tha for some specifications right now in the project (bosses, etc...) we can't upgrade to API 23 , to use library compats that contains this method.

SO my question is:

There is any way to handle the request of the permissions, doing some workaround?

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="xx.xx.otr.app.providers.imps.permission.READ_ONLY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="xx.xx.otr.app.providers.imps.permission.WRITE_ONLY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="es.in2.otr.app.im.permission.IM_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="xx.xx.otr.app.im.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="xx.xx.otr.app.im.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="xx.xx.otr.app.im.permission.IM_SERVICE"
        android:description="@string/perm_desc"
        android:label="@string/perm_label"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    <permission
        android:name="xx.xx.otr.app.providers.imps.permission.READ_ONLY"
        android:description="@string/ro_perm_desc"
        android:label="@string/ro_perm_label"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    <permission
        android:name="xx.xx.otr.app.providers.imps.permission.WRITE_ONLY"
        android:description="@string/wo_perm_desc"
        android:label="@string/wo_perm_label"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

Comment: set targetSdkVersion 22 and don't ask runtime permissions then check it will fine. Other you can check the version of android and request permissions accordingly.I found a beautiful tutorial for requesting permissions at runtime. read it you will get to know what to do http://coderzpassion.com/android-new-runtime-permissions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this link

"The easiest way to manage runtime permissions is by using third-party libraries"
PermissionsDispatcher is specially developed for dangerous permissions

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Managing-Runtime-Permissions-with-PermissionsDispatcher